# Plot.ly: Logic for one graph controlled by multiple dropdowns

Tags: python, plotly

In the Plot.ly code below via the Python API, I show one of cos(x)/cos(2x)/sin(x)/sin(2x) based off the selection in a dropdown menu. I would like to amend it such that there are two dropdown menus: one for choosing cos/sin and the other for choosing x/2x. There is already a second, dummy dropdown menu which is identical to the first just for presentations sake.

Is Plot.ly capable of doing this? So far I'm only aware of editting what is visible via the `visible` tag in the buttons dictionary which takes a static list, so I'm not sure if the presentation logic is sufficient.

Plot.ly graph is here:

https://plot.ly/~cnmartinez11/58/cos1x/#/

Code (runnable in a Jupyter notebook):

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import numpy as np

xx = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
funcs = [np.cos, np.sin]
omegas = [1, 2]
buttons = []
data = []
n_plots = len(funcs)*len(omegas)
visible = [False] * n_plots

cnt = 0
for func in funcs:
    for omega in omegas:

        name = '{}({}x)'.format(func.__name__, omega)
        visible_current = visible.copy()
        visible_current[cnt] = True

        buttons.append(
            dict(
                label = name,
                method = 'update',
                args = [
                    {'visible': visible_current},
                    {'title': name}
                ]
            )
        )

        trace = go.Scatter(
            x = xx,
            y = func(omega*xx),
            visible = True if cnt == 0 else False,
            name = name
        )
        data.append(trace)

        cnt = cnt + 1

updatemenus = [dict(buttons = buttons), dict(buttons = buttons, y = 0.75)]
layout = dict(title='cos(1x)', updatemenus = updatemenus, hovermode = 'closest')
fig = dict(data = data, layout = layout)
# py.iplot(fig)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I assumed it wasn't possible in pure plotly. It's simple enough in Dash.

```
app = dash.Dash()

func_map = {'cos': np.cos, 'sin': np.sin, None: np.cos}

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='function-select',
                options=[{'label': 'cos', 'value': 'cos'}, {'label': 'sin', 'value': 'sin'}],
                value='cos'
            )
        ],
        style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block'}
    ),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='arg-select',
                options=[{'label': 'x', 'value': 1}, {'label': '2x', 'value': 2}],
                value=1
            )
        ],
        style={'width': '20%', 'display': 'inline-block'}
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='sinusoid-graph')
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('sinusoid-graph', 'figure'),
    [
        dash.dependencies.Input('function-select', 'value'),
        dash.dependencies.Input('arg-select', 'value')
    ]
)
def update_graph(func_name, omega):
    func = func_map[func_name]
    xx = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    yy = func(omega*xx)

    data = [go.Scatter(x = xx, y = yy)]
    layout = go.Layout(
        title = '{}({}x)'.format(func_name, omega),
        hovermode = 'closest'
    )

    return {'data': data, 'layout': layout}
```